# Get error codes when attempting to make a call from an android application?

Tags: android

When trying to make a call through my own application on an android cell phone, can I get the type of error (if any, like call disconnected, switched off etc) from that call? [not asking how, just, is that possible?] And also, can we get some kind of 'true' signal when attempting to make a call and knowing that 'yes the other phone is ringing', can we get information like that? (kinda like, when the other person's phone is ringing, you can hear it on the speaker like 'tring tring' :P, but can we register that 'tring tring' automatically by an application when trying to make the call?)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. stackoverflow is not a Q&A forum.

Comment: Thank you! :D
And sorry. :3

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the detailed phone state, that is private to the system.

All you can get are idle/ringing/offhook etc. rough status.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of that.  The [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) handles all of that.  Just some example states you can get:

```
int CALL_STATE_IDLE Device call state: No activity.
int CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK  Device call state: Off-hook.
int CALL_STATE_RINGING  Device call state: Ringing.
int DATA_ACTIVITY_DORMANT   Data connection is active, but physical link is down
int DATA_ACTIVITY_IN    Data connection activity: Currently receiving IP PPP traffic.
int DATA_ACTIVITY_INOUT Data connection activity: Currently both sending and receiving IP PPP traffic.
int DATA_ACTIVITY_NONE  Data connection activity: No traffic.
int DATA_ACTIVITY_OUT   Data connection activity: Currently sending IP PPP traffic.
int DATA_CONNECTED  Data connection state: Connected.
int DATA_CONNECTING Data connection state: Currently setting up a data connection.
int DATA_DISCONNECTED   Data connection state: Disconnected.
int DATA_SUSPENDED  Data connection state: Suspended.
```

Comment: Please explain which of these you believe would solve the **particular problem** of the question.  Note that most of what you posted has nothing to do with *voice calls*.

Comment: You set up a BroadcastReceiver that listens for android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE and using that you can tell if a call is ringing, connected, or hung up.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the CALL_STATE_RINGING applies to outgoing calls?  I have seen it suggested that it only applies in the incoming case, and that seems consistent with the documentation: "Device call state: Ringing. A new call arrived and is ringing or waiting. In the latter case, another call is already active."

Comment: Thank you DShaw for the detailed reply! :)
But as Chris stated, even I found in the documentation that part where it states "Device call state: Ringing. A new call arrived and is ringing or waiting", now, my question is, does it tell if the other person's phone has started ringing or not?